# Magnetic Field at centre of Hemisphere

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

MY APPROACH:

I know that we have rotate by an angle theta from centre  and take an angular element which corresponds to a ring and write the expression for field accordingly. But my main problem is that i am not able to interpret how the turns of the wire are distributed. I assumed that they are distributed over the surface area uniformly however that lands up the value for 'N' as 3. However the answer given is 4. All I need to understand is how the turns vary with angle theta. It would be great if someone could help me out with this one

Comment: How did you come up with $n=3$ for uniform distribution of wires?

Comment: I deviated from the centre by an angle theta and considered a ring and wrote the expression for magnetic field due to a ring and integrated that

Comment: Yes, your are right $n=3$ for the unform looping.

Comment: In order to have $n=4$, the distribution has to be uniformly distributed in the arc length: $dN = 2N \frac{d\theta}{\pi}$, details see the following post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a current looping uniform arc distribution. The loop density per arc length
$$
  \lambda = \frac{N}{\pi R / 2}
$$
the nunber of loops $dN$ between $\theta$ and $theta + d\theta$:
$$
  d N(\theta) = \lambda R d\theta =  \frac{2 N}{\pi} d\theta.
$$

These rings at angle $\theta$ contribute a magnetic field of:
$$
   dB = \frac{\mu_o R^2 \sin^2\theta }{2 R^3} \frac{2 N i}{\pi} d\theta,
$$
The total field is:
$$
   B(O) = \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \frac{\mu_o N i \sin^2\theta }{\pi R} d\theta
$$
$$
   = \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \frac{\mu_o N i}{\pi R} \frac{1-\cos 2 \theta}{2} d\theta
$$
$$
   = \frac{\mu_o N i}{2 \pi R} \left[ \theta - \frac{\sin 2 \theta }{2} \right] _{\pi/2}^\pi
$$
$$
   =  \frac{\mu_o N i}{2 \pi R} \frac{\pi}{2} =  \frac{\mu_o N i}{4 R}
$$

We assume the uniform arc distribution to obtain $n=4$.

Comment: I understood now. Thanks.